# Video Editing with openGL android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, opengl-es

can we edit video with **opengl** ?  want to apply some effect on video, filter video, add text or image at particular time farm, Cut video so 
if there is any library for edit video then please suggest me..

Comment: You definitely can't use OpenGL on android, there is only OpenGL-ES available. Unfortunately, asking us to recommend a library or other off-site resource is off-topic on SO.

Comment: want open source any video editing lib so can you have? @BDL

Comment: So how do we do Video Editing using OpenGL in the first place, with effects as asked by the @GauravPrajapati